# How to validate long PathParam in Spring

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I would like to validate input of following `@RequestMapping`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Response getCategory(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
   // some logic here
}
```

When consumer of the endpoint passes string following error occurs:

```
Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Long]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
```

I could change it to string but I believe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: The message says "null" is not a Long, try requesting "/1" or "/2", not "/null".

Comment: This is thing I want to prevent - users calling with `null` to my endpoint

Comment: I think this post will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493767/can-pathvariable-return-null-if-its-not-found

Comment: you could use a regex for `{id:[0-9]+}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from [RC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180100/rc) is a very good way to make sure your id will be made of digits.

In general if you want to validate incoming requests you could also create and register a custom interceptor by implementing HandlerInterceptor and then add your validation in the overridden preHandle method.

Comment: link broken as of 2021-01-06 919am CST